# Jenkins Templates

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees

I am new to the Cloudbees Enterprise of Jenkins and to the concept of "templates".
I am trying to define a new template and this template will be used by 20-30 number of jobs. The job is a basic build job. After the build, I would like to have  code analysis plugin. How can I define it in the Jenkins Template.
I can define it while creating a direct job in "Post Build Actions" but not sure how to define the same in a template.

Do you have any solutions/ suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudbees templates plugin is very powerful but not easy to master. Creation and administration of templates is not as user-friendly as one wishes it to be. ;)

For an introduction I recommend reading the following resources:

- [Basic concept](https://www.cloudbees.com/products/cloudbees-jenkins-platform/enterprise-edition/features/templates-plugin)
- [Template documentation](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html#template)
- [Tutorial for simple job template](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html#temolate-sect-job-template-tutorial)

Make sure you understand the difference between *builder template* and *job template*. I assume you want to create a number of jobs using the *job template*. Follow these steps:

1. First of all create a normal job that contains all actions you want to perform by all templated jobs.
2. Make sure this job works as expected for one example configuration.
3. Now create a new job template:

   - You will need to decide, which parts of the job configuration need to be adapted to each jobs configuration (e.g. source code repository). Create an parameter for each configuration option.
   - You might want to do some pre-processing on the job templates parameters using some transformation script - but we skip that for now.
   - Now you need to add an XML description of what the generated job should do. I recommend copying this XML description from our example job created in step #1. You can access it via this URL: `http://your-jenkins/job/this-job/config.xml`. Simply copy&paste the XML code in the browser. Newer Jenkins versions also allow to read the jobs XML configuration via the user interface.
   - Finally you need to fill in the templates arguments within the XML configuration. Simply replace the specific (hard-coded) values by a reference to the name of the templates parameters created before: `${param_name}`
   - Save the template
4. Now create a new job. On the job creation screen you should be able to select your newly created job template as job type. After creating a job of the templates type you can define all template parameters for this specific job.
5. Try to run the template-based job and make sure it works as expected.
6. Create more template-based jobs as needed.

All template-based jobs share the build steps defined by the job template. If you change the job template later on, all depending jobs are updated accordingly. This is a very efficient way to administrate a large number of similar jobs. It is very much worth the effort. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will try as you suggested and will update.